# One piece english dubbed

Tags: one-piece

I heard from here at least that the release date for episodes 555-574 english dubbed will be released on March 20th for one piece. What the frick is going on. Unless someone's info. Was wrong. The episodes should be up.

Comment: While it has been resolved in the answer, I'm curious from where you heard about this, because when I searched for "one piece 574" or "one piece dub" on this site, I didn't get any result other than this question.

Answer (score 0):

according to both [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_One_Piece_episodes_(seasons_15%E2%80%93current)#English) and [Rightstuff](https://www.rightstufanime.com/One-Piece-Season-9-Part-4-DVD) the DVD Release of the 4th part of Season 9 (Season 9, Fourth Voyage which covers Episodes 553-563) is the 20th of March 2018 and as of writing this (21/03/2018 GMT+10/11) it is in stock (as opposed to pre-order) as such the information is correct if it was talking about DVD release

for the rest (564-574), Part 5/Fifth Voyage isn't expected to be out until the 15th of May and still [only a Pre-order on Right Stuff](https://www.rightstufanime.com/One-Piece-Season-9-Part-5-DVD)

this is further backed up by [English Dubbed Anime Lovers](http://www.english-dubbed.com/knowledge-bazaar/upcoming-english-dubbed-release-dates/)

[image: Upcoming One Piece Releases 21/03/2018]

> The episodes should be up.

if by this you are referring to Streaming i can't check [Funimation](https://www.funimation.com/shows/one-piece/) as Geoblocking prevents Australians from viewing the page however as it is Funimation who releases the dubbed DVDs it's likely they have it up there already (since the DVD is out for 553-563)

[Chrunchyroll](http://www.crunchyroll.com/one-piece/episode-555-deadly-attacks-one-after-another-zoro-and-sanji-join-the-battle-657997) has had the episodes since atleast Jul 26, 2014 though it might be the subbed version and the [series list](http://www.crunchyroll.com/one-piece) doesn't list anything about subbed or dubbed.

Comment: http://www.english-dubbed.com/knowledge-bazaar/upcoming-english-dubbed-release-dates/ Season 9, Voyage 4 is 553 to 563.

Comment: @кяαzєя ahh right, i forgot about the other half